# In OpenCart3 how to prevent adding extra characters in $this->cart->add(...)?

Tags: opencart, encode, cart, opencart-3

I'm customizing OpenCart3. For some reasons I have to save contents of `cart` table in a session, then re-insert them back, but while adding session data using `$this->cart->add(...)` extra codes are added to options which I don't know how to prevent.

```
foreach($this->session->data['in_cart']['rows'] as $key => $row){
    if ($row['store_id'] != $this->session->data['cart_store_id']) {
        $this->cart->add($row['product_id'], $row['quantity'], $row['option'],  $row['recurring_id'], $row['store_id']);
    }
}
```

Originally options should be saved like:

```
{"90":["263"],"89":["260"]}
```

But they get saved as:

```
"{\"142\":[\"494\"],\"141\":[\"492\"]}"
```

Thanks for any kind help, but not `down voting`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by decoding the saved string into array, then adding it:

```
foreach($this->session->data['in_cart_total_products_all_stores']['rows'] as $key => $row){
    if ($row['store_id'] != $this->session->data['cart_store_id']) {
        $options = json_decode($row['option']);
        $this->cart->add($row['product_id'], $row['quantity'], $options,  $row['recurring_id'], $row['store_id']);
    }
}
```